# How to tell java that this number could become long during runtime?

Tags: java, long-integer

I'm running this code where a number could end up being too big to be an integer.

I define this number:

```java
long num = 0L;
```

at the very beginning, but still, when it's getting too big, like 9,999,999,991, it couldn't be this large, it would be something like 1410065408.

My question is, how can I let java compiler know that this number could become too big, just make it long all the way during calculation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `BigInteger`. It can stuff an arbitrary long number

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Both `9,999,999,991` and `1410065408` fit in a long.

Comment: Also it depends a bit on how it becomes large.  Are you incrementing it by one?  Multiplying by one thousand?  This could make a difference.  Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) , it take the memory dinamicaly so he dont have limit.